# Is Thunderbird usable in 2019?

Tags: thunderbird

I would like to download and send emails using Thunderbird. 
Besides being free, open source and with solid history, it has a number of attractive aspects (such as for example, not downloading images by default so that the senders are not able to track whether the emails are opened).

I use Gmail (IMAP) and an account on another server (also IMAP). I tried using it for a couple of months, but I am still having problems and starting to think about giving up:

- Repeated messages about the need to compact my folders (these did end after I agreed to compact, even though the purpose of this operation and the reported sizes were unclear to me).
- Failing to store sent emails on the server (although it might be a remote server problem).
- And now: re-downloading all of my 30k emails from Gmail each time I open Thunderbird.

Is it possible to use Gmail via Thunderbird without trouble? Is there any simple and modern tutorial?

Comment: Can I recommend Geary? I find that to be a better application.

Comment: @Persistence My favorite is evolution. That's a huge matter of taste :)

Answer (score 19):

I wonder since when was the last time you used Thunderbird on Ubuntu. It must have been a very long time ago. Such issues were present then but not now.

I have been using Thunderbird with Gmail and a number of other IMAP providers for years with none of the mentioned issues.

I have extensively examined newer versions of Thunderbird with IMAP and all is okay. So I assume if you plan on using IMAP, no problem at all using new versions of Thunderbird on Ubuntu.

One issue might arise though, that is Thunderbird prompting you to compact folders. This, however, can easily be overcome either by dismissing this operation when prompted or by disabling this feature completely from preferences by removing the check mark like in the image below:

[image]

Here is a recommended tutorial: [Thunderbird and Gmail](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-gmail)

---

Regarding Thunderbird re-downloading emails using IMAP from Gmail each time you open it. This can happen if its local copy of the folder has reached the file size limit for your file system. The file size limit for **FAT32** for example is **4 GB** but on Ubuntu's file system **Ext4** this is unlikely to happen as the file size limit for **Ext4** is a whooping **16 TB**. Please read [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Repeatably_downloading_the_same_messages).

If, however, this is not the case, then please follow the steps below to reset Thunderbird's indexes. Thunderbird keeps track of messages in your IMAP folders using `.msf` files which stands for “Mail Summary files”. Data corruption in these files, which can happen for various reasons, may cause Thunderbird to loose track of your messages and re-download them again and again.

In your account settings, select **Server Settings** like in the image below:

[image]

Copy the path of the **Local Directory**, open a terminal and type `cd` then press <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> **once** then paste the path then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Once inside the path of the mail account's Local Directory, please **close Thunderbird** then run the following command in your terminal:

```
find . -type f -name '*.msf' -exec mv {} {}.old \;
```

Now open Thunderbird. New `.msf` files will be rebuilt and messages will be re-downloaded hopefully once and for all this time.

---

Regarding Thunderbird Failing to store sent emails on the server. If it happens sometimes, then it is most likely the remote server's problem. If, however, it happens every time, you might need to take a look at your account settings under copies & folders -> **When sending message, automatically** -> **Place a copy in** select **Other** then choose **Sent Mail on your-email@gmail.com** from the drop down menu like in the image below:

[image]

---

---

Explanation - as requested by [r2evans](https://askubuntu.com/users/399638/r2evans):

**r2evans** wrote in the comments:

> Just curious, Raffa, you emphasized in bold the "once" in "type cd the
>   press space bar once then paste the path". Is there a reason that one
>   (vice two or more) spaces is important here? – r2evans

This is to promote good practice and consistency. In this case, the bare minimum expected by the `cd` utility is one space and no extra spaces are required.

That being said, extra spaces will work as well.

However, upon reading [Ubuntu Manpage - cd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/cd.1posix.html), the following is noted:

> This  manual  page  is part of the POSIX Programmer's Manual.  The
>   Linux implementation of this interface may differ (consult the
>   corresponding Linux manual  page  for  details  of Linux behavior), or
>   the interface may not be implemented on Linux.

Also, upon reading [cd - change the working directory](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html), the following is noted:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> cd [-L|-P] [directory]
>
> cd -
> ```

Also, upon taking [Utility Conventions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) into consideration.

One might reach the conclusion that it is worth noting to press the <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> **once**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still have no solution for 3. -  the profile size is 4 GB, but I'm using ext4 and this problem occurred today (2019-08-19) on version 60.8.0.

Comment: @Valentas kindly, see the updated answer. Best of luck

Comment: Just curious, Raffa, you emphasized in **bold** the "once" in *"type `cd` the press space bar once then paste the path"*. Is there a reason that one (vice two or more) spaces is important here?

Comment: @r2evans I updated the answer with response to your comment. Thank you

Comment: Can you link to a "shell (script) best practices" (for `bash` or another common shell) that makes mention of multiple spaces between arguments? The `cd` man page is unrelated: there's no mention of multiple spaces; and *documentation* typically uses single spaces between args, perhaps for aesthetics/compactness or to not imply that multiple spaces are required. Regardless, it and the "utility conventions" are red herrings: the utility (including `cd`) never sees the space(s) between arguments, it's the shell's job to pack/collect the arguments and `exec` the utility (or call the function).

Comment: Welcome back @r2evans Multiple spaces still work, but there is no guarantee it will stay like this. It makes sense to follow the documentations as they are most likely going to be taken into consideration of developers in the future. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/976835/1054416) explains what I have in mind. I hope I explained. Have a nice day and stay healthy.

Comment: Interesting points, Raffa. While I disagree on some points, I think (1) this site is not about discourse, and (2) it is mostly just opinions. (I'll stop polluting this Q/A with my blather.) Thanks!