# Thunderbird: Emails in Inbox folder cannot be displayed after migrating from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, email, thunderbird, indexing

When I was migrating from Windows 7 to Ubuntu, I took my Thunderbird profile and copied it into the Thunderbird profile folder under Ubuntu. When I started Thunderbird, everything worked fine and all emails of my three email accounts could be displayed. But there occured an error with just **one** email account that did not affect the other two: I could not read my emails that were saved in its `Inbox` folder.

Now, I am able to see the **list of *all* emails** in the `Inbox` folder but I cannot open them. When I try to open a message, a blank page appears. Strangely enough, however, the content of these emails that cannot be displayed is still shown when I am using Thunderbird’s search functionality. Moving the emails in the `Inbox` folder to another folder does not help. If I do that, they are still not displayed when I click on them.

I do not know why this just happened to one out of my three accounts and why all the emails in its `Inbox` folder are affected but not the other ones that reside in other folders.

What might be the problem and how can it be fixed?

Comment: And what email account has the problem?

Comment: Well, does it help you if I say that it is the second one?

Comment: What I mean is, is it a gmail or hotmail etc account and are the other that work?

Comment: The two accounts that work are a Web.de and a Gmx.de account. The one that does not work is now hosted by Host Europe.

Comment: Assuming that all three accounts are IMAP, delete the profile copied over from Windows, restart TB, and setup the three accounts manually... or to prove that doing so would fix the problem, just create a new profile (thunderbird -P), and recreate the account that's having the problem, and see if it works again.

Comment: It is a `POP` account. Web.de is an `IMAP` account and Gmx.de is a `POP` account as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest trying to repair the folder index `(.msf)` file. This file may become damaged and result in such issues.

For each profile, Thunderbird stores messages from email folders in files with the same name as the folder's name and with **no file extension** for example (the Inbox folder's messages are saved in a file called `Inbox` and the Drafts folder's messages are saved in a file called `Drafts` and so on ... ). These files contain the complete messages of the corresponding folder and can get very large in size and a size of a few gigabytes is not uncommon. Therefore Thunderbird relies on **mail summary files** or `.msf` to avoid slow responses due to loading messages from very large files every time it starts or the user searches for emails.

**Mail summary files** or `.msf` files are used by Thunderbird to index messages in each mail folder. These files only contain messages headers. They are smaller in size and faster to load and search.

One **mail summary file** exists for each folder so for example (the Inbox folder will require two files: one is to store the actual full messages which will be called `Inbox` and the other file which will be called `Inbox.msf` will contain only messages summary AKA messages headers for indexing and searching purposes).

If the mail summary file gets corrupted or missing, that is not a big deal because it does not contain the real messages but rather an index or a reference to them and it can be fixed.

If, however, the messages storage file itself gets corrupted or missing, that's a different story and emails will most likely be lost forever.

To repair the folder index `.msf` file, please **back up your original profile first** then start Thunderbird and **right click** on the `Inbox` folder of the affected email account and choose **Properties** from the menu. Then click on the <kbd>Repair Folder</kbd> button like in the image below:

[image]

After the repair process completes, please restart Thunderbird and check if the problem is solved.

---

**Workaround:**

If the above method does not work for you, then I would suggest a workaround using `Evolution` mail client. This workaround is aimed at enabling you to list and view your old inbox messages. Please follow these steps to implement this workaround:

**First:** If you do not have **Evolution** installed, you can install it by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install evolution
```

**Second:** Start Evolution and go to **File** menu -> **Import** and you will be presented with a dialogue box like in the image below:

[image]

**Third:** Click the <kbd>Next</kbd> button and choose **Import a single file** like in the image below and click the <kbd>Next</kbd> button again like in the image below:

[image]

**Fourth:** Click on the field next to **Filename** to open the file browser like in the image below:

[image]

**Fifth:** Brows to your email profile and find a directory named `[Mail Account Name].sbd` and click on it like in the image below:

[image]

**Sixth:** Find the messages file named `AllMail` or `Inbox` with no extension depending on your original mail folder and double click it like in the image below:

[image]

**Seventh:** Click the <kbd>Next</kbd> button like in the image below:

[image]

**Eighth:** Choose the destination folder and click the <kbd>Next</kbd> button like in the image below:

[image]

**Ninth:** Click the <kbd>Apply</kbd> button and wait for the operation to finish like in the images below:

[image]

[image]

**Done:** Your messages should be available in **Evolution** mail client in good shape in the destination local folder you chose during this process.

Comment: After doing what you suggested, the index in my `Inbox` folder is now completely gone but my messages can still be found via the **global** search function of Thunderbird. But don’t worry: I have backed up everything before.

Comment: Do I have to use Evolution from then on if I am going to do this and cannot switch back to Thunderbird? Will it repair my file so that I can import it into Thunderbird?

Comment: @Nemgathos This is to rescue your old inbox. You can reset the `.msf` indexes of your current account in Thunderbird so it downloads new messages using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1166751/968501) . Will it repair your file? yes. Will you be able to import it into Thunderbird? maybe but no guarantee as the format is different between the two clients

Comment: @Nemgathos Please, keep backups always

Comment: Regarding my original backup: There is no file called `inbox` without an extension. All other folders, however, have this file. When I tried to repair the `Inbox` folder with Thunderbird, a file called `inbox` without extension was created but I cannot import this file into Evolution.

Comment: @Nemgathos The name varies depending on what your original `inbox` folder was called. It could be `Mail`, `All Mail`, `Old Mail` or any other name. Basically all files without extensions in that folder are messages files. They usually have larger file sizes in MB or GB. The folder also contains your `Sent` and `Draft` messages and you can retrieve them as well. Look into your original backup. The `inbox` file in Thunderbird is probably created as a result of the repair process and most likely empty and has a very small size in bytes.

Comment: Ok, all of this seems to be very strange. My folder is called `Mail`. This folder contains the `mail.affectedaccount` folder. This folder contains two files of all folders – except `Inbox` which just has one file called `Inbox.msf` (2.8 MB). `mail.affectedaccount` contains a subfolder called `INBOX.sbd`. There, I can find two files for `Drafts` and `Trash`, a folder called `Trash.sbd` and three files with 0 bytes in size (`Archives.msf`, `Sent.msf`, `Templates.msf`) but no file is called `Inbox`.

Comment: @Nemgathos It seems your Inbox message file was called `Inbox` and it should be in the same folder next to the `Inbox.msf` file. Unfortunately it seems missing! Probably it was not backed up in the first place. What you can do though is to try and import all message files you find to Evolution like `Drafts` and `Trash` and any others available to see if they contain any messages just in case you moved emails to trash somehow before back-up.

Comment: By trying out what you suggested, I just noticed that `mail.affectedaccount` contains a file called `Trash.msf` but no `Trash` file. I believe that this folder was empty when I migrated from Windows 7 to Ubuntu. Importing `Draft` and other folders is not a problem. But they do not contain the messages of `Inbox`.

Comment: @Nemgathos No messages file means nothing can be done because it was not backed-up from windows correctly in the first place. I hope you still have the messages on the mail server so you can download them again. I really wish there was a back-up and I could help.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case. That’s all I have. I wonder why I can find all the contents by searching for them but that it is still impossible to access the messages regularly. Should I try importing my old emails on a Windows computer into Thunderbird? I’m afraid this will not help either. Regarding the “messages file”: Do you mean `Inbox`?

Comment: @Nemgathos I mean by messages file like `Inbox` with no extension. Regarding searching for messages and they show up, this is insignificant unless you can actually view the full body of the messages and not only the subject. If you can view the whole messages after searching for them then the `Inbox` file should be there somewhere in your profile and you need to expand your scope and look for it in all folders until you find it and then you can import it into Evolution. Otherwise the search results could be coming from the `Inbox.msf` file which contains only messages  headers,

Comment: I have **finally** found the `Inbox` file after searching for it on my external hard drive on which the original copy of the backup is stored. **But I don’t know why it was not copied when I copied all files to Ubuntu.** It has a size of 482 MB and contains all my emails that I can now read again! Edit your answer accordingly. I have already marked it as the best answer.