# How to import .sbd directories into ThunderBird?

Tags: thunderbird

I presently have some old .sbd directories which I would like to import into ThunderBird as 'Local Folders':

[image: [1]Local Folders]

Any advice on how to import these directories?

[image: [2].sbd directories]

Comment: You just copy them under your profile directory in `~/.thunderbird/` ... [Related post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1319671)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quit Thunderbird and copy these folders into the "~/.thunderbird/########.default-default/Mail/Local Folders" folder, where ####### is a string of random letters and numbers unique for your user profile. Make sure your user is owner and has the right to create and delete files in the folders you copied.

On restarting Thunderbird, a corresponding `.msf` index file will automatically be created, and the folders will appear under "Local Folders" in Thunderbird, where you still could move them to other folders if you wish.

The "ImportExportTool NG" right-click menu item probably is not standard and comes from an extension you choose to install. Apparently, it only allows to import `mbox` files one at a time. Folders in Thunderbird in which messages reside are represented by a single `mbox` file, which actually is a specially formatted text file containing all messages and attachments. These mbox files *do not have a file name extension*. Their name corresponds with a folder containing email messages in Thunderbird.

In your second screenshot, the file "Church" will contain a few messages in the Thunderbird folder "Church". The file "Church.msf" is an automatically generated index file, automatically recreated if it is deleted. In that folder "Church", you have created subfolders. These are written in the folder "Church.sbd". If you do not have subfolders, an ".sbd" folder will not be created. If you have subfolders, the ".sbd" folder will be removed if you delete all these in Thunderbird.

Comment: Thank you @vanadium for explaining.

Also managed to find the answer at:
https://rb.gy/xawzov

Comment: With this, you now also have a procedure not requiring an extension that may break with future Thunderbird versions.

Comment: great bro thanks